Cannot have the model.py file after training my lstm model over sst2 datatset without adversarial training
Describe the bug
A clear and concise description of what the bug is.
To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
Run following command textattack ...
Run following code ...
See error
Expected behavior
There should be a module.py file generated after training lstm over sst2 dataset using the command below
textattack train --model lstm --dataset sst2 --epochs 20 --early-stopping-epochs 3

Screenshots or Traceback
While trying to attack my best_trained model using the command below
textattack attack --model-from-file ./outputs/2024-11-28-11-41-55-920215/best_model/model.py \
--dataset-from-huggingface sst2 \
--attack-recipe deepwordbug \
--log-to-txt results_deepwordbug.txt

textattack: Loading datasets dataset sst2, split train.
textattack: Loading model and tokenizer from file: ./outputs/2024-11-28-11-41-55-920215/best_model/model.py
textattack: Loading module from `./outputs/2024-11-28-11-41-55-920215/best_model/model.py`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/skywarrior/Desktop/texattack/textattack-env-310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/textattack/model_args.py", line 192, in _create_model_from_args
    model_module = load_module_from_file(args.model_from_file)
  File "/Users/skywarrior/Desktop/texattack/textattack-env-310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/textattack/shared/utils/importing.py", line 63, in load_module_from_file
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 879, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1016, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1073, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/skywarrior/Desktop/texattack/./outputs/2024-11-28-11-41-55-920215/best_model/model.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/skywarrior/Desktop/texattack/textattack-env-310/bin/textattack", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/skywarrior/Desktop/texattack/textattack-env-310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/textattack/commands/textattack_cli.py", line 49, in main
    func.run(args)
  File "/Users/skywarrior/Desktop/texattack/textattack-env-310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/textattack/commands/attack_command.py", line 31, in run
    model_wrapper = ModelArgs._create_model_from_args(attack_args)
  File "/Users/skywarrior/Desktop/texattack/textattack-env-310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/textattack/model_args.py", line 194, in _create_model_from_args
    raise ValueError(f"Failed to import file {args.model_from_file}.")
ValueError: Failed to import file ./outputs/2024-11-28-11-41-55-920215/best_model/model.py.

The contents of the best_model ss
enter image description here
System Information (please complete the following information):
OS: MacOs
Library versions (e.g. torch==1.7.0, transformers==3.3.0)
Textattack version
Additional context
I am trying to reproduce the textattack paper's adversarial training figure the image is attached below
enter image description here
Can someone please help me to reproduce the above figure I would be very grateful to learn and understand why it is or not reproducible
I have tried to train the model and run the attack but it was not possible. I wanna reproduce the results

What is your question? The exception tells you exactly what the issue is

Once you’ve created my_model.py, you can run an attack using TextAttack’s command-line interface by specifying your custom model file:
textattack attack --model-from-file my_model.py --recipe textfooler --num-examples 10
Ensure that my_model.py is in the current working directory or provide the full path to the file. This command tells TextAttack to load the model and tokenizer from my_model.py and perform the specified attack recipe (textfooler) on 10 examples.
Additional Tips:
•   Verify Model and Tokenizer Paths: Ensure that the paths in my_model.py correctly point to your saved model and tokenizer files.
•   Check Dependencies: Make sure all necessary libraries (e.g., PyTorch) are installed and compatible with your model.
•   Consult Documentation: Refer to TextAttack’s FAQ for more information on using custom models.
